# How to display "True" if there are items in a list on an asp:DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, datagrid

Here's my setup:

```
public class A
{
   string FirstName{get;set;}
   string LastName{get;set;}
   List<Object> MyItems{get;set;}
}
```

my aspx page setup:

```
<asp:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ID="dgMyData" CellPadding="7">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EntryDate" HeaderText="Entry Date" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

My question:

Assuming I'm using class A (or List myList) as a datasource,
I would like to add another column here to say "Yes" or "True" if there are items in the MyItems list.  I don't need to display the items on this page, but I need to indicate whether they exist or not.

How would I go about doing this?  I have looked at itemtemplate columns but am a bit uncertain how to do it for this data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps you / if I understand the problem, but creating a new column and bind it to

```
(MyItems.Any()).toString()
```

helps you ?

you can also have

```
MyItems.Any() ? "items exist" : "no items"
```

the simplest solution would be to add a new property to hold the text string you want to display, like the following:

```
public class A
{
   string FirstName{get;set;}
   string LastName{get;set;}
   List<Object> MyItems{get;set;}
   string Info {get { return MyItems.Count > 0 ? "items exist" : "no items"; }}
}
```

and add a new column to the template adding

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Info" HeaderText="Items Exist ?" />
```

If you do not want to change your object class, try using a template column, like:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Items Exist ?">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%#(Container.DataItem("MyItems") as IEnumerable<object>).Any()%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @Andre: right, yours is more elegant indeed. Thanks

Comment: @oppassum: What is your grid supposed to display ?  A list of A objects?

Comment: @Veverke as stated in my question, I want to display "Yes" or "True" if there is an item in the list.

Comment: am not sure what I have just added works, have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this on a new page, then it is better to use asp GridView instead of DataGrid. GridView is successor to Data Grid and offers more flexibility.

DataGrid was an ASP.NET 1.1 control. GridView is in 2.0. For more information on comparison please read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was a successor I just hadn't looked

Answer (score 0):

So the proposed answer (and one I was trying to avoid) was to add another variable to my object class.

Since this class is used in quite a few places and I didn't want to add an object, I was able to determine a way to solve this with ItemTemplate:

```
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Int32.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Files.Count").ToString()) > 0 ? "Yes" : "No" %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: yeah, I have just added a template column as well. But without using Eval